# uEnv.txt to boot.scr newer version u-boot issues

Tags: linux, bootloader, openwrt, u-boot

I did use a older version (should be 2014.10) to create my openwrt image with uboot. it works fine.

For some reason, I need to use newer version(2016.XX), I follow the same steps to build my SD, when I boot up, and some errors like this(sorry if picture is not good to use)

[image]

then I check the environment variables. 
I use the command "printenv bootenv loadbootenv"(not sure if it's right)

result is like this

printenv bootenv loadbootenv

## Error:"bootenv" not defined

loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenvfile}

then I try to set "uEnv.txt" as bootenv variable, still cannot boot up

shows, Unrecognized filesystem type

I do have a uEnv.txt file with me and it's already configed by others. I have no knowledge to config the environment thing...

and it looks like new version u boot like boot.scr instead of uEnv.txt

are there anyway to convert uEnv.txt to boot.scr? or if there are any wiki about how to set up a boot.scr step by step.

Thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks no one likes my question.....

I gave up on this and switch to another version of boot loader. which will read either uEnv.txt or boot.scr.